# Failure:while installing Git plugin in jenkins 2.7.4

Tags: git, jenkins, offline

Getting the Below error while installing the Git Plugin manually with Git.hpi file by going to Jenkins -> Plugin Manager -> Advanced -> Upload plugin.

```
java.io.IOException: Failed to dynamically deploy this plugin
at hudson.model.UpdateCenter$InstallationJob._run(UpdateCenter.java:1883)
at hudson.model.UpdateCenter$DownloadJob.run(UpdateCenter.java:1640)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at hudson.remoting.AtmostOneThreadExecutor$Worker.run(AtmostOneThreadExecutor.java:110)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to install git plugin
at hudson.PluginManager.dynamicLoad(PluginManager.java:866)
at hudson.PluginManager.dynamicLoad(PluginManager.java:807)
at hudson.model.UpdateCenter$InstallationJob._run(UpdateCenter.java:1879)
... 5 more
Caused by: jenkins.MissingDependencyException: One or more dependencies could not be resolved for git : mailer (1.17), ssh-credentials (1.12), git- client (2.0.0), matrix-project (1.7.1), credentials (2.1.4), workflow-scm-step  (1.14.2), scm-api (1.2)
at hudson.PluginWrapper.resolvePluginDependencies(PluginWrapper.java:529)
at hudson.PluginManager.dynamicLoad(PluginManager.java:856)
... 7 more
```

Can Anyone please tell the reason for this error and resolution steps?
Thanks In Advance.

Comment: Did you read the error message? "Caused by: jenkins.MissingDependencyException: One or more dependencies could not be resolved for git". Looks like you need to download all these hpi files too, so that git has all its dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

```
Caused by: jenkins.MissingDependencyException: One or more dependencies could not be resolved for git : mailer (1.17), ssh-credentials (1.12), git- client (2.0.0), matrix-project (1.7.1), credentials (2.1.4), workflow-scm-step  (1.14.2), scm-api (1.2)
```

It says it right there that you're missing the following dependencies:

- [mailer](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Mailer)
- [ssh-credentials](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/SSH+Credentials+Plugin)
- [git-client](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Git+Client+Plugin)
- [matrix-project](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Matrix+Project+Plugin)
- [credentials](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Credentials+Plugin)
- [workflow-scm-step](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Pipeline+SCM+Step+Plugin)
- [scm-api](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/SCM+API+Plugin)

Out of curiosity, why are you installing it manually when you can install it via the Plugin manager? If you install it from the plugin manager it'll also install all the dependencies for you.

Comment: Hi Fadi, i uploaded latest version of Jenkins.war in tomcat.So when i tried using Plugin Manager to search and install plugin it is giving nothing to download the plugin.I don't know whether it is connecting to internet or not,but i am working in a machine where it has access to internet.
Tell me one thing are these dependencies are to be downloaded manually and upload before the main git.hpi is uploaded.

Comment: Try logging into the machine and ping a public site (like try maybe pinging `jenkins-ci.org`) and see if it works.. If it does then check if you have the update site set to: `http://updates.jenkins-ci.org/update-center.json`